# how to get the number from a string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I want to how know to get certain numbers from a string in matlab. For example, I have a string:

'ABCD_01  **36**_00 **3** .txt', (there is spacing between 01 and 36)

What I need is to get the number 36 and 3. How can I do it in matlab? I've tried finding the answer from previous posts but can not find one  that fits this purpose. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are the filenames always in this form?

Comment: the length of ABCD may vary but other than that every thing will follow this form.

Comment: @Tai-YenChen: regular expression are well suited for these types of problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the filenames always start with four characters you can do:

```
>> filename = 'ABCD_01 36_00 3 .txt';
>> sscanf(filename, '%*4c_%*u %u_%*u %u.txt')

ans =

    36
     3
```

Comment: if the length of the character ABCD will vary, how will you fix that?

Comment: you can generalize that as: `sscanf(filename, '%*s %u_%*s %u')`

Comment: @Tai-Yen Chen: If there will always be a space after that first integer then Amro's suggestion will solve the variable prefix issue.

Answer (score 10):

Regular expressions:

```
>> str = 'ABCD_01 36_00 3 .txt';
>> t = str2double( regexp(str,'.* (\d+)_.* (\d+)','tokens','once') )

t =
    36     3
```